# Custom text representation for sum type

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble grappling with how to turn a sum type into a string without doing a whole bunch of pattern matching. A [simplified] example might be something like this:

```
data Shape = Rectangle Int Float Float |
             Circle Int Float |
             Ellipse Int Float Float
             deriving (Show, Eq)
```

What I want is a function `renderShape :: Shape -> String` that takes a `Shape` and gives me a string that represents the argument in a certain way (I'm generating lines in an input file for a simulation program). Note that I would like this to be distinct from `show`, as it is doing a bit of extra formatting beyond just turning the data structure into a string. What I actually need it to do is kind of complicated, but for example purposes (because if you can explain generally how to do this I think I can work out the rest), let's just say I want to stick a semicolon on the end and separate with a comma e.g.

```
renderShape $ Rectangle 1 2 2
>> "Rectangle,1,2,2;"
```

Specifically, what I'm struggling with is that the different constructors for the type have varying number of arguments. I could do something with pattern matching, like

```
renderShape (Rectangle i x y) = (intercalate "," ["Rectangle", show i, show x, show y]) ++ ";"
renderShape (Circle i x) = ...
...
```

but I'd prefer not to as in reality I have a ton of these types of shapes so it'd be awfully tedious.

I've found something that "works" by abusing the derived `show` instance and simply transforming the string, but it seems really ugly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.List (intercalate)

renderShape :: Shape -> String
renderShape s = intercalate "," theWords ++ ";"
  where theWords = (words . show) s
```

So my question is, what's the "nice" way to do this? It seems to me like there has to be a simple and clean way to go about it, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. I'm also not hugely experienced with Haskell, so if my whole approach is fundamentally wrong or non-idiomatic then I'd welcome alternatives.

Comment: Perhaps generics or SYB can help here, as long as you can add some `deriving ...` causes and enable a few GHC extensions. Template Haskell can also be used, I believe, but it looks overkill for this.

Comment: I played with TH some but it was a lot of headache. I figured there had to be something simple.

Comment: PS: The reason I say it seems easy is because the auto-derived show *almost* does what I want, I just want to tweak it a bit. I know that `deriving Show` invokes some magic under the hood, but it's so tantalizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an *ideal* usage of generics. Our strategy will be to convert the datatype into its generic representation (`from :: (Generic a) => a -> Rep a`) and then recurse into `Rep a`. `Rep a` is actually a type function, so let's see what it looks like:

```hs
λ> :info Shape
[lots of garbage]
type instance Rep Shape
  = D1
      Main.D1Shape
      (C1
         Main.C1_0Shape
         (S1 NoSelector (Rec0 Int)
          :*: (S1 NoSelector (Rec0 Float) :*: S1 NoSelector (Rec0 Float)))
       :+: (C1
              Main.C1_1Shape
              (S1 NoSelector (Rec0 Int) :*: S1 NoSelector (Rec0 Float))
            :+: C1
                  Main.C1_2Shape
                  (S1 NoSelector (Rec0 Int)
                   :*: (S1 NoSelector (Rec0 Float) :*: S1 NoSelector (Rec0 Float)))))
```

Oof. We're in higher-kinded territory here. To traverse this data structure we'll need to recurse into the type itself. Whereas value recursion works by repeatedly calling a function on smaller and smaller parts of a data structure, we will create a one-method class called `Jason` and then instantiate the method on smaller and smaller parts of the type.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.Generics

data Shape = Rectangle Int Float Float |
             Circle Int Float |
             Ellipse Int Float Float
             deriving (Show, Eq, Generic)

class Jason a where
  jasonShow :: a -> String

-- Integers can use the regular show.
instance Jason Float where jasonShow = show
-- So can floats.
instance Jason Int where jasonShow = show

-- Constant values are easy.
instance (Jason c) => Jason (K1 i c p) where jasonShow = jasonShow . unK1

-- Use generics to pattern match into constructors.
instance (Jason (f p), Constructor c) => Jason (M1 C c f p) where
  jasonShow constructor@(M1 x) = conName constructor ++ "," ++ jasonShow x

-- We don't care about selectors.
instance (Jason (f p)) => Jason (M1 S c f p) where
  jasonShow (M1 x) = jasonShow x

-- Or whether something is a datatype or not.
instance (Jason (f p)) => Jason (M1 D c f p) where
  jasonShow (M1 x) = jasonShow x

-- We don't care about the index into the disjoint union (a.k.a. "|") of a datatype.
instance (Jason (f p), Jason (g p)) => Jason ((f :+: g) p) where
  jasonShow (L1 x) = jasonShow x
  jasonShow (R1 x) = jasonShow x

-- We want to insert a comma when we encounter a product in the datatype.
instance (Jason (f p), Jason (g p)) => Jason ((f :*: g) p) where
  jasonShow (x :*: y) = jasonShow x ++ "," ++ jasonShow y

renderShape :: Shape -> String
renderShape = (++ ";") . jasonShow . from
```

To output commas for products and the name of the constructor, we special cased those instances:

- `M1 C c f p` is a type for the meta-information (`M`) for a constructor (`C`) wrapped around a value `f p`. Calling `conName` on a value of this type will helpfully return a string representing the name of the constructor.
- `(f :*: g) p` is a type for the product of two values of type `f p` and `g p`. Earlier, when we queried for the type of our rectangle, you can see this appear in a couple of places. For example `M1 S NoSelector (Rec0 Float) :*: M1 S NoSelector (Rec0 Float)` (I expanded out the `type S1 = M1 S` alias). You can think of `:*:` as the glue between the numbers in `Rectangle 1 2 2`.
- Our base cases in the recursion are `Int` and `Float`. We can keep defining more base cases, but our shape is just ints and floats.

This is pretty weird code! You don't see so so many esoteric datatypes with weird two-character names everyday. But we did arrive at this nice result:

```hs
λ> renderShape (Rectangle 1 2 2)
"Rectangle,1,2.0,2.0;"
λ> renderShape (Circle 1 2)
"Circle,1,2.0;"
λ> renderShape (Ellipse 1 2 2)
"Ellipse,1,2.0,2.0;"
```

It's also a lot of code. But it's *generic* code, which means you can reuse it with other, non-Shape datatypes.

#### on language extensions

- DeriveGeneric: allows `derive (Generic)`, which automatically instances `Generic` for our datatype `Shape`.
- FlexibleContexts: without this, we can't say `instance (Jason (f p), Constructor c) => Jason (M1 C c f p)`. The Haskell spec disallows constraints like `Jason (f p)`. `Jason p` is OK, but `Jason (f p)` is no go. Fortunately, GHC is flexible.
- FlexibleInstances: allows destruct `M1 i c f p` into three different instances: `M1 C c f p`, `M1 D c f p`, and `M1 S c f p`. Normally disallowed by the spec.
- TypeOperators: allows the usage of infix type functions `:*:` and `:+:`.

### see

- [GHC.Generics documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/GHC-Generics.html)
- [Using generics to implement JSON encoding/decoding](https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/master/Data/Aeson/Types/Generic.hs)
- [This implementation of Show (just regular Show) with generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving-0.3/docs/src/Generics-Deriving-Show.html)
- [You could've invented GHC.Generics](http://jozefg.bitbucket.org/posts/2014-04-25-you-could-have.html) – a great tutorial

Answer (score 2):

You could derive `Data.Data` for your ADT, which exposes a generic descriptor for any custom data type. Then you can write a function that renders any instance of `Data` in the not-quite-like-Show fashion you need. It's certainly overkill for a single smallish type like Shape, but you could reuse it for multiple, larger types.

I'm not totally familiar with the API for doing so, but http://chrisdone.com/posts/data-typeable ends with an example of writing a generic function with a signature close to `gshow :: Data d => d -> String`.

Comment: I came across that article too and came up with something that works well enough [here](https://gist.github.com/jasonmhite/1fa474351af5d14a66ff), but I can't say I really understand *why* it works. I'm having a hard time figuring out what is going on with `toConstr`.